# Is there a XPages equivalent of the JSF <ui:debug /> tag?

Tags: xpages, jsf-1.2

In JSF there is a  tag that renders to the screen the component tree representing the View (page) on the server.

It also has the session scope variables.

I know about the XPages Toolbar (use it everyday).  However, it does not give me the component tree hierarchy like the JSF  tag renders.

If your a JSF developer reading, XPages extends the JSF 1.2 runtime, its registered as the View Handler. API classes http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/Designer/9.0.1/index.html

Can I include standard JSF tags with my XPages tags on the single page and build it?

I tried putting this in xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{appBean.version}">    </xp:text>

  <ui:debug />  

</xp:view>
```

Build error is: 
The unknown namespace tag ui:debug cannot be used as a control, as the namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets is not known.

Answer (score 3):

The  Inspector tab will allow you to see the component tree. I used it at IBM Connect and Engage to show the difference in component trees between a basic repeat (MartyRepeat) and one with `repeatControls="true"` set (TannenRepeat). It also showed only a single facet is loaded into the Dynamic Content control. The limitation is that the list and hierarchy of components doesn't change dynamically, so dynamicContent1's descendants don't update.

[image: Component Tree]

Answer (score 1):

The closest you get to `<ui:debug />` is the [debug toolbar](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPage%20Debug%20Toolbar) available on OpenNTF.

The other options, AFAIK path never traveled, would be to add the JSF libraries as plugins into Domino. Might be interesting from an engineering perspective, but most likely not worth the trouble.

Hope that helps